# Limits, if the limit exists or not

Tags: limits

[image]

For the following graph there are some questions, i did couple of them but some of them are saying wrong, these are the wrong ones.

```
lim x→−1 F(x) = 4

lim x→1 F(x) = 3

lim x→3 F(x) = Does not exist

F(−1) = DNE

F(1) = DNE
```

Comment: We have $F(1) = 3$, can you see why?

Comment: Well, look at the graph,  Clearly $F(1)$ exists, for example.  $F(1)=3$.  That's what that solid dot means.  Similarly, what do you think $F(-1)$ is?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Yes, ... those are wrong.  What's your question?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to-1}F(x)=4$.  If you look at the function for the values of $x$ near $-1$ but not equal to negative $1$ you see the values of $F(x)$ are all near $3$.  So $\lim_{x\to-1}F(x)=3$. (It's important to notice that at $x=-1$, $F(x)$ "jumps off the graph" and $F(-1)=4$.  But at the values near *but not equal* to $-1$, $F(x)$ "approaches" $3$.  So $\lim_{x\to -1}F(x)=3\ne 4 = F(-1)$ and $\lim_{x\to -1}F(x)\ne F(-1)$.)

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 1} = 3$.  If you look at function for values of $x$ near but below $1$ you see $F(x)$ is approaching toward $2$.  Bu if look at values of $x$ near but above $1$ you see $F(x)$ is approaching toward $3$.  So the limit from below is $2$ but the limit from above is $3$.  These are not consistant so the $\lim_{x\to 1} F(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 3} F(x)=$Does no exist.  Well, nothing is *equal* to "does not exist".  Either a limit exists and it doesn't.  If it doesn't exist, it doesn't equal.  It is not equal to the words "Does not exist".  But anyway... If you look at the function for values of $x$ near but not equal to $3$ we see the values of $F(x)$ approach $2$.  So $\lim_{x\to3}F(x)=2$.  And *AT* $x=2$ there's a huge hole in the graph and the function $F(x)$ at $x=2$ does not exist.  But limits are about the value of $F(x)$ *near* $x=3$ but *not equal* to $3$ and at values *near* $x=3$ the function approaches $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$F(a)$ refers to what the function is doing when $x$ is *EXACTLY* equal to $a$.

$\lim_{x\to a} F(x)$ refers to how the function behaves at values of $x$ where $x$ is *near* $a$ but where $x$ does *NOT* equal $a$.

So.....

ONE and FOUR

at $x=-1$ then function "jumps off its track" and has that dark red value at $4$.    But when $x$ is *close* to $-1$ but $x$ is *not* equal to $-1$ we see the function is on a  track and is approaching the value of $3$ so...

- $F(-1)= 4$
- $\lim_{x\to -1} = 3$.

TWO and FIVE

and $x = 1$ the function takes on the value of $3$. At $x$ near $1$ but $x < 1$ we see the function was approaching $2$ but "ripped itself" and jump to $3$ at $x = 1$.  And the values of $x$ near $1$ but $x > 1$ we see the function is approaching $3$.  As the function is approaching one value for $x$ near but less than $1$, and is  approaching a *different* value foor $x$ near but more than $1$, there isn't any one consistent value that the function approaches when it is near but not equal to $1$.  So

- $\lim_{x\to 1} F(x)$ does not exist.
- $F(1) = 3$.

By the way, we don't ever say something "$= $ does not exist".  "Does not exist" is a statement that something doesn't exist. It's not a number or a value.

THREE (and a non-asked for SIX)

At $x=3$ there is no value of the function.  There's a hole in the graph.  So the value $F(3)$ does not exist.  If we look at the values of $x$ *near* but not *equal* to $3$ we see the function approaches the value of $2$. So

- $\lim_{x\to 3} F(x) = 2$.
- $F(3)$ does not exist.